How can I use multithreaded BLAS from a single threaded EIgen C++ application?
I'm trying to speed up Eigen dense matrix * matrix operation by using multihreaded BLAS library calls.
I've achieved 100% speed increase using AMD AOCL-BLAS library from within Eigen. But I seem unable to force the BLAS library to run multiple threads. Running Eigen itself multithreaded with openmp does not seem to make any major difference in my application.
What's the correct solution here ?

The BLAS library itself has to be compiled with parallelization enabled: https://github.com/flame/blis/blob/master/docs/Multithreading.md Not sure how AOCL is typically packaged but for OpenBLAS, distributions typically provide a libopenblas.so which is single-threaded and a libopenblas_openmp.so which is multithreaded. Link accordingly

Linking with MT enabled AOCL-LibBlis-Win-mt-dll.lib instead of AOCL-LibBlis-Win-dll.lib worked!
